# Does visiting not existing image URL affects web server?

Tags: javascript, php

I'm planning to set a short polling that loads image URL instead of using `AJAX` just to check if the image is already uploaded from the other hardware device(camera, fingerprint, etc...).

Does visiting not existing image URL every seconds affects or slow web server? Is it the same of `AJAX` short polling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it has nothing to do with the slowing or fastening web server, its all about need of your application.

Usually short polling AJAX is used in order to avoid "image not found" exception. If you have some other way of handling it or if it's not a need of your application, go right ahead and load as many non existing images as you like, it won't affect any web server speed.

However, I do not recommend doing AJAX call every second if you decide to go that way because the completion of an AJAX request depends upon the internet speed of the end user and in case of slow net, browser might queue many AJAX requests which might create issues for your application.

Also, in that case, your script will use the last response returned from server which might not necessarily be the response of the last AJAX made and you might end up showing wrong results. The same thing for which we use debounce in search process.

*I hope it helps*